# Передать в метод arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

есть три arrayList:

```
private ArrayList<Clothes> clothes = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Computer> computers = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Smartphone> smartphones = new ArrayList<>();
```

есть switch который в зависимости от выбранного передает в метод arraList:

```
switch (checkInt()) {
        case 1:
            searchName(clothes);
            break;
        case 2:
            searchName(computers);
            break;
        case 3:
            searchName(smartphones);
            break;}
```

собственно вопрос: как метод searchName должен принимать arrayList

```
searchName(???????????????){
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList<Product>` где `Product` - класс родитель для всех перечисленных

Comment: интерфейс нужны для таких случаев

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Максим,

сразу бросилось в глаза, что у вас тип переменно класс, а не интерфейс. Best практика советует использовать как раз-таки интерфейс, например:

```
private List<Clothes> clothes = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Computer> computers = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Smartphone> smartphones = new ArrayList<>();
```

Касательно Вашего вопроса, можно использовать generic методологию:

```
public <T> void searchName(List<T> list)
```

В вопросе неизвестно являются ли классы Clothes, Computer и Smartphone наследниками какого-то другого класса или интерфейса. Если бы они таки являлись, например:

```
interface Goods {
    int price();
    int name();
    int amount();
}

class Clothes implements Goods {
...
}

class Computer implements Goods {
...
}
```

То в таком виде код бы стал более лаконичным:
Инициализация:

```
private static List<Goods> clothes = new ArrayList<>();
private static List<Goods> computers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Наполнение:

```
clothes.add(new Clothes());
computers.add(new Computers());
```

Метод остался бы унифицированным:

```
public void searchName(List<Goods> list) {
     for (Goods entity : list) {
         System.out.println(entity.price());
     }
}
```

А вызов метода одинаковый для каждой из коллекций:

```
searchName(clothes);
searchName(computers);
```

В худшем случае в варианте с generics можно будет определять какой именно объект пришел, используя instanceof оператор.

Comment: Спасибо, это пока для меня не понятно, но буду читать. Перечисленные классы являюся наследниками одного класса, который в свою очередь является наследником от главного класса.

Comment: В таком случае логично сделать:
private List<Родитель> clothes = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Родитель> computers = new ArrayList<>();

Метод:
searchName(List<Родитель> list)

Вызов:
searchName(clothes);
searchName(computers);

Comment: Спасибо! Не до конца понятно но работает) Думаю в процессе разберусь!

Comment: **А ещё best practices говорит что элементы одно типа(интерфейса) можно хранить в одном контейнере** и ещё много других вещей.

Comment: Ну это уже зависит от того как человек хочет построить свою структурную композицию. Я все же считаю, что бест практики - это то, как "надо" делать, а не как "можно". Но в принципе да, можно и объединить... =)

Answer (score 2):

Передать вот так:

```
searchName(ArrayList<Object> objects){
}
```

Но Вам же нужно организовать поиск в этих массивах?!
Тогда вам нужно определить один интерфейс для всех этих классов. Назовем его, например **Searchable**. В нем опишем функцию getName(). тогда можно будет передавать в функцию параметры так:

```
Searchable searchName(ArrayList<Searchable> searchableList){
   for (Searchable element in searchableList){
       if(element.getName() == "My some name")
           return element;
   }
}
```