# Как передать ArrayList в качестве аргумента

Tags: java

Имеется первый класс `One` с конструктором, принимающим в качестве аргумента `ArrayList` типа `String`, :

```
class One{
   ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>(); 

   One(ArrayList<String> a){
        for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
            this.al.add(a.get(i));
}
```

Имеется второй класс `Two` (агрегирующий массив типа `One`):

```
class Two{
    ArrayList<One> a = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addValue(One one){
        a.add(one);
    }
}
```

Как правильно записать передачу аргумента типа `ArrayList?

```
Two two = new Two();
two.addValue(????);      // тут нужно добавить текст "тактовая частота"
two.addValue(????);      // тут нужно добавить текст "процессор" и "объем ОЗУ"
two.addValue(????);      // тут нужно добавить "дорожка", "стек", "сортировка"
```

P.S. Читал [этот топик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702663/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-arraylist)

---

ОТВЕТЫ:

---

**1. Метод "двойной скобки":**

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("text1");
    add("text2");
    add("text3");
}};
```

**Какие ещё есть варианты?**

Comment: Вот про "метод двойной скобки": https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1457-double-brace-inicializacija

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. я бы написал класс One так:

   ```
   class One{
      ArrayList<String> al; 

      One(List<String> a){
          al = new ArrayList<>(a);
      }
   }
   ```
2. А вот решение:

   ```
   two.addValue(new One(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"тактовая частота"})));
   two.addValue(new One(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"процессор", "объем ОЗУ"})));
   two.addValue(new One(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"дорожка", "стек", "сортировка"})));
   ```

Comment: А правильно  ли записан в данном случае конструктор у вас? У меня код не компилируется данным образом. Или нужно сделать так: `public <T> One(List<T> asList) {
    }`

Comment: У меня компилируется(по крайней мере строчка new One(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"d","d"}));). public нужен если вы хотите получить доступ к классу вне текущего пакета. А дженерик - только если вы точно не знаете тип, который должен лежать в ArrayList. Зависит от задания.

Comment: Что-то я запутался. У вас стоит `;` в вашем примере `new One(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"d","d"}));)`

Comment: @n199a в конце была закрывающая скобочка(текст был в этих скобках)

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо вам. Далее интересна дискуссия по поводу двойных кавычек.

Answer (score 2):

Как по мне, есть варианты лучше и проще. Например, так :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class One {

    List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();

    One(String...names) {
        al.addAll(Arrays.asList(names));
    }
}

class Two{

    List<One> a = new ArrayList<>();

    public Two addValue(One one){
        a.add(one);
        return this;
    }

    public Two addValue(String ... one){
        return addValue(new One (one));
    }

}

class Test {
    public void test (){
        Two two = new Two()
                .addValue("тактовая частота")
                .addValue("процессор", "объем ОЗУ")
                .addValue("дорожка", "стек", "сортировка");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Two{
  ArrayList<One> a = new ArrayList<>();

  public Two addValue(One one){
    a.add(one);
    return this;
  }
}

Two two = new Two().
  addValue(new One(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("тактовая частота"); }})).
  addValue(new One(new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("процессор"); add("объем ОЗУ"); }}));
```

Comment: Что скажете о том, что здесь считают, что это антишаблон? https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1457-double-brace-inicializacija

Comment: Вот тоже собрался только что задать этот вопрос вам

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar "возможным утечкам памяти" - после этих слов я не стал читать дальше

Comment: @Igor, аргументируйте, пожалуйста, чтобы стало понятно что вы имеете ввиду. P.S. javarush не люблю читать, там переписано как-то из книг так, что не понятно

Comment: @Igor но то, что вы создаете анонимный класс - факт. Думаете, это оправдано? Кстати, при вводе double brace по первым же 4 ссылкам указывают, что это антипаттерн и указывают на проблемы данного способа инициализации. Тем более в данном случае изначально size = 0, поэтому массив будет увеличиваться и увеличиваться, что очень дорого

Comment: Хотя, это(size = 0) уже не проблема. Вы можете указать в скобках размерность массива - new ArrayList<String>(size){{...}} - конструктор суперкласса вызовется раньше, чем блок инициализации подкласса. Но все равно остаются казусы с анонимным классом и общественным мнением.

Comment: А анонимный класс достаточно много "кушает": https://habr.com/ru/post/313350/ . Хотя бы поэтому я не стал бы использовать этот способ инициализации.